# Music player with automatic scoring of music (playing songs increases score, skipping song decreases it) for Linux

Tags: linux, automation, music

I am looking for a music player that will include automatic score field, increased when substantial part of song is played and decreased when song is skipped.

I also need option to sort music by this coring field and search for music by its title.

It also needs to work on Linux, as an installable software (not a website).

I am currently using [Clementine](https://www.clementine-player.org/), but sadly this project is dying, with last release in [2016](https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine/issues/5958). Clementine has rather too many features than not enough, so just maintenance releases would be enough. But sadly it is often crashing for some reason, with bitrot accumulating since 2016.

Answer (score 1):

[Quod Libet](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/downloads.html) has a plugin that "Rates songs automatically when they are played or skipped". It is worth trying out. You will have to enable the plugin via "Plugin" menu, then select "Automatic Rating".

It is open source, and runs on Linux, Windows, MacOS.

It is typically updated say once a year or more, but development is ongoing via [github](https://github.com/quodlibet/quodlibet).

I have used QuodLibet for years, but not tried this feature myself.

Answer (score 0):

While https://github.com/clementine-player/Clementine has still not made a release, Debian packages were created using more recent code from the repository.

This fixed problem of recurring random crashes and automatically generated rating feature is still present.